# Argument matching not working properly with NSubstitute

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, httpclient, nsubstitute

I have this code and I can't get httpClient to return the string response no matter what.

```
HttpClient httpClient = Substitute.For<HttpClient>();

httpClient.PostAsync("/login", Arg.Any<StringContent>())
          .Returns(this.StringResponse("{\"token\": \"token_content\"}"));

Console.WriteLine(await httpClient.PostAsync("/login", new StringContent(string.Empty)) == null); // True
```

Here is the `StringResponse` method if someone wants to reproduce this:

```
private HttpResponseMessage StringResponse(string content)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    if (content != null)
    {
        response.Content = new StringContent(content);
    }

    return response;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

It works when I do

```
httpClient.PostAsync("/login", Arg.Any<StringContent>())
              .ReturnsForAnyArgs(this.StringResponse("{\"token\": \"token_content\"}"));
```

But I don't need just any arguments, I need one of them to be the string `"/login"` and the other to be of type `StringContent`.

I tried to put something more general in the `Arg.Is` call like `HttpContent` but that doesn't work too.

I'm using `NSubstitute 2.0.0-rc`on .NET Core, but I also tried using `NSubstitute 1.10.0` on standart console application and got the same result.

Comment: Which version of nsubstitute are you using? (I'm trying to reproduce the issue now.)

Comment: I am using 2.0.0-rc with .Net Core but tried this code with 1.10.0 on normal console application and got the same result.

Comment: Hmm. Reproduced it, but haven't managed to fix it yet...

Comment: I assumed that I was doing something obviously stupid with NSubstitute because it's my first time using it.

Comment: I suspect this is the problem: "Warning: Substituting for classes can have some nasty side-effects. For starters, NSubstitute can only work with virtual members of the class, so any non-virtual code in the class will actually execute!" `PostAsync` isn't a virtual method...

Comment: But if you try `ReturnsForAnyArgs` it works.

Comment: `public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string requestUri, HttpContent content)` it is not virtual method

Comment: NSubstitute is "constrained" mocking framework - you can fake only virtual members or interfaces.

Comment: I think that if that was the problem it wouldn't have worked with ReturnsForAnyArgs insted of Returns.

Comment: Well, I dont' know why `ReturnsForAnyArgs` works (it would be worth updating the question with that) but it does feel like you're somewhat off the supported functionality.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that the `public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsync(string requestUri, HttpContent content)` method isn't virtual and NSubstitute cannot correctly link your argument specification and return value to the method. That's a problem of all mocking libraries based on `Castle.Core`.

What's important is that NSubstitute links the specification to the first virtual method in the execution stack which turns out to be `public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)` method somewhere down the stack. You were "lucky" to have the same return type in it. And as you can see it has different arguments that obviously don't match with those you provided. Surprisingly `ReturnsForAnyArgs()` works because it doesn't check the argument specification you provided.

Comment: I would have never figured out that one on my own, thank you!